# Automate evaluation of formulae

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, libreoffice-calc

This is my situation:

1) A and B change values often. I can write and save them in .xls with **xlwt**.

2) X.xls   process their values with some formula, but xlwt would not evaluate the formula and **return only 0**.

3) if I open X.xls and save from **LibreOffice**, then I get the results.

4) with **xlrd** I can now read the results from Python.

How can I automate the **3)** step in Python?

Just use subprocess or are there better solutions?

Comment: Is the spreadsheet really required? is python required?

Comment: I'm on a django 1.7.5. project, and different peoples will manage xls files, so yes, both are required